# Show items with no data doesn't work when implementing filter. Power BI desktop

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

In order to display all months till the end of the year I checked "Show items with no data" and everything worked fine.

[image]

But then I implemented filter on column PremiumSum (greater than 0) and future months are gone.

[image]

"Show items with no data"  is still checked. But I am not able to bring months till the end of the year.

Is any workaround for that?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because `BLANK()` is not greater than `0`. Maybe try putting "Or is blank" on your filter.

Comment: Like always right :) 
Please post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter is causing them to disappear because a blank is not greater than `0`.

It should work if you add a second condition of "is blank" using the Or so that it will return all items greater than zero or that are blank.